# How will ProcessingTimeoutTrigger in Flink work with nested Trigger which can fire on processing time?

Tags: apache-flink

I was looking at source code of *ProcessingTimeoutTrigger* which suppose to wrap any *Trigger* adding trigger-on-timeout functionality. I wonder how will it work with *nestedTrigger* that register, for example, its own Processing time timers.
According to implementation:

```
@Override
public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long timestamp, W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    TriggerResult triggerResult = this.nestedTrigger.onProcessingTime(timestamp, window, ctx);
    if (shouldClearOnTimeout) {
        this.clear(window, ctx);
    }
    return triggerResult.isPurge() ? TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE : TriggerResult.FIRE;
}
```

It will trigger *WindowFunction* no matter on *nestedTrigger* invocation result.
I wonder why? If this timer was registered with *nestedTrigger* and appears prior to the one registered with *ProcessingTimeoutTrigger*, why are we firing?

Same question goes to onEventTime implementation. *ProcessingTimeoutTrigger* does not register any eventTime timers. Which means that onEventTime will be called for a timer registered with *nestedTrigger*. Why, in this case, we are always firing?

Shouldn't we somehow check if current fired timer is actually the one registered by *ProcessingTimeoutTrigger*? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't noticed the existence of `ProcessingTimeoutTrigger` before, so this is just my take based on reading the code and tests and [FLINK-17058](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17058) (the ticket that added this feature).

[testWindowPurgingWhenInnerTriggerIsPurging](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.14/flink-streaming-java/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/operators/windowing/ProcessingTimeoutTriggerTest.java#L171) tests the case that I would be worried about with a nested `ProcessingTimeTrigger`, which is to test that the wrapping timeout trigger is purged when the nested trigger is purged. That way if the nested trigger fires and is purged before the outer one, the outer one will be purged. And if the inner trigger fires without purging, then the outer one should remain in place.

Looks to me like `onEventTime` is assuming that if the nested trigger registered an event time timer, then when that timer fires the window should FIRE. That feels a bit sloppy, but in practice is very unlikely to be wrong.

Comment: I think I understand the fist part, however i don't see logic handling namely nested-trigger-fires-or-purges scenario... Which makes this implementation simply invalid for nested timing triggers. Is my understanding correct?